# recover deleted uefi partition grub 2

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I have deleted my UEFI partition, because I thought it prevent me to make dual booting system...:) So now I know, that was my fault. I want to recover my uefi partition. I have created 512MB partiton in the start of disk, I have set it's id as 'EF', I have created folder /boot/EFI on it. I mount this point and chroot it. When I'm trying to install grub-efi, bash says, that this is not an efi partition. What's wrong? Please, if you know good step-by-step guide, give me the link. Thank you for advance.

Upd. my current partitions:
[partitions.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/588rG.png)

Comment: Boot into UFD Live Ubuntu, run `sudo parted -l`.  Edit your question with results.

Comment: You have a problem. Your output says you are trying to run an MBR drive as a UEFI. Furthermore you have an ESP boot that will only run correctly on a GPT drive, not an MBR one. I presume  your BIOS is set up for **UEFI** instead of **Legacy** (MBR).  So you will need to go into BIOS and confirm what setting you are on at the moment. Is Windows still on the drive? What is on the 193GB and 537GB partitions?

Comment: @PaulBenson I see UEFI with Legacy mode enabled in my BIOS. I thought, that UEFI supports MBR too, isn't it? As I know, converting MBR table to GPT will erase all my data, am I wrong? There are personal data on the 193GB and 537GB partitions. And I don't want to lose it) Yes, Windows still on the drive, on the second partition.

Comment: Legacy mode is a UEFI option for those who have an MBR disk. You've set up an EFI boot which will only work on a GPT one. If you convert to GPT and switch to full UEFI then you will lose everything on there, so you start from scratch. Alternatively do a boot-repair and stay on Legacy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My partition table was MBR, and it hindered me to start UEFI loaders. I have converted table with **gdisk** util to GPT without losing of my data. Now UEFI works fine